# How to load a contributed module load before a custom module?

Tags: 7

I have a custom module which is having dependency on contributed module.

How can i make sure that contributed module will be loaded before custom module ?

Answer (score 2):

You could [update the module weight](https://www.drupal.org/node/110238) so that it is lower than that of the contrib module meaning it would get loaded first.

Comment: This is only response that actually answers the asker's question.

Answer (score 1):

In your custom modules **.info** file add the following line.

`dependencies[] = contrib-module-name`

For more info refer [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/542202).

And add the [module_exists](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_exists/7) condition in your code.

```
$module = 'required module name';
if(module_exists($module)){
  Your Code;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This doesn't make sure that a module is loaded after its dependencies; it just make sure a module is not installed/enabled if its dependencies are not enabled too.

Comment: Thnx @kiamlaluno. I updated my answer.

Comment: This still does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to load a specific file or function, you may include the related file using [module_load_include](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7).